# Running multiple shell commands using std::process::Command

Tags: rust

I am trying to insert multiple commands using `std::process::Command` on Rust instead of running a
bash script. I have read the concept of running multiple commands using the example cited here, from the [`execute`](https://docs.rs/execute/) crate:

https://docs.rs/execute/latest/execute/#execute-multiple-commands-and-pipe-them-together.

```
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};

use execute::Execute;

let mut command1 = Command::new("echo");
command1.arg("HELLO WORLD");

let mut command2 = Command::new("cut");
command2.arg("-d").arg(" ").arg("-f").arg("1");

let mut command3 = Command::new("tr");
command3.arg("A-Z").arg("a-z");

command3.stdout(Stdio::piped());

let output = command1.execute_multiple_output(&mut [&mut command2, &mut command3]).unwrap();

assert_eq!(b"hello\n", output.stdout.as_slice());
```

The problem is these commands are being written in a scattered format. I would like to know if there are better ways to add subcommands directly as arguments under `Command::new()` instead of having to segregate them as `command1`, `command2` etc.

Comment: Those are not shell commands, you are executing the `echo` / `cut` / `tr` processes directly. If you want to execute a shell and have the shell do all the pipework in one single  `Command`, you have to run a shell. For example, you can run `/bin/bash` with the `-c` argument (see the `bash` manpage) to give `bash` a shell script. Something to the tune of `Command::new("/bin/bash"); cmd.arg("-c").arg("echo 'Hello World' && cut -d -f1")`

Comment: Yes this approach worked.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [shutil](https://crates.io/crates/shutil) crate simplifies running multiple commands. Install it with:

```
cargo add shutil
```

You can then run your example pipeline like so:

```rust
use shutil::pipe;

fn main() {
    // Executes `echo "HELLO WORLD" | cut -d " " -f 1 | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'`
    let output = pipe(vec![
        vec!["echo", "HELLO", "WORLD"],
        vec!["cut", "-d", " ", "-f", "1"],
        vec!["tr", "A-Z", "a-z"],
    ]);

    // prints "hello"
    println!("{}", output.unwrap());
}
```